# I'm a predator I have a pray

Tags: riddle, knowledge

## I'm a predator I have a pray

---

> I'm a predator I have a pray
>   Make sure you stay away
>   Since my laser glowing eyes
>   Will keep me safe from flies
>
> I'm a predator I have a pray
>   They always say I may
>   But really what I mean
>   Is the one who's not stray
>
> I'm a predator I have a pray
>   I'm found there all the day
>   You couldn't live without me
>   They even let me see
>   The files that are free

---

*This puzzle requires a tiny bit of knowledge which is used in the 3rd paragraph. The first and second paragraphs require no knowledge.*

## Spoilers:

> No typos here.

---

> What's the answer to every riddle with "pray" in the name?

---

<sub>(Sidenote, not a clue: Riddle actually rhymes quite good, try singing it)</sub>

Comment: Is Pray meant to be spelt with an A as a hint or an E to become Prey (the opposite of Predator)?

Comment: @AHKieran I "dont" know :P

Comment: oh whoops, just read the spoilers (usually we call them hints so I thought the spoilers would be more answery)

Comment: That's the point, I called them spoilers because they almost give it away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the answer:

> Cat?

**I'm a predator** I have a pray
Make sure you stay away
Since **my laser glowing eyes**
Will keep me safe from flies

> Cats are a predator. Their eyes are known to reflect the light. You also mentioned in a clue that the answer to other puzzles involving the word "pray" are connected - several of them on this site are "cat".

I'm a predator I have a pray
They always say I may
But really what I mean
Is **the one who's not stray**

> Stray cats.

I'm a predator I have a pray
I'm found there all the day
You couldn't live without me
They even let me see
**The files that are free**

> I thought this refers to a different kind of "cat" - a 'catalogue' file in computing. But thanks to @Josh for pointing out that the 'cat' command in UNIX / LINUX is for reading files (amongst other things). Perhaps the word 'free' refers to the open source nature of LINUX?

Comment: You almost got it but missing 1 thing posted by Josh which should've been hidden with rot13.

Comment: Reposting my comment in rot13: [[ png vf n Havk hgvyvgl gb ernq svyrf ]] The reason I didn't do it is because I was sure this answer was wrong, and I was just drawing further random connections.